# What is the best way to add support for SSO to a Rails SaaS app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on

I run a small SaaS platform that allows businesses to whitelabel my solution into their existing websites.  I've had a few potential customers ask if I support SSO.

I've never built out SSO before - what would be the best way to support allowing 3rd parties to integrate their existing user accounts via SSO into my app?  I already have my own authentication system using Devise.  I'm concerned adding SSO support would add another complex layer around the existing authentication model?

Comment: I manage a handful of Rails apps for a healthcare company that were built in-house and also integrate with 3rd party vendor applications.  We too use Devise for authentication as well as customizations to Doorkeeper and the Oauth 2 protocol. It's worked well for us as an approach to SSO, but it's certainly not the only way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn a Rails app with Devise into a SSO/CAS server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879419/how-to-turn-a-rails-app-with-devise-into-a-sso-cas-server)

Comment: Or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215831/rails-authentication-across-apps-servers